# I've added a scroll bar to my div, but why isn't it working?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I'm trying to add a vertical scroll bar to my div, and I have the code there however it's just not working, it's likely I'm doing something wrong, but could someone please help?

This is what I have already, and I am using the browser FF, however it's not working in any browser I open.

```
width: 200px;
left:20px;
top:10px;
padding:10px;
position: fixed;
float:left;
overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
height:600;
background-color:#ffffff;
border:solid 1px #e2e2e2;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The length unit has been unregarded for the `height`. It should be `height: 600px` or whatever else.

Comment: Besides, the computed value of 'float' is 'none' when the element is positioned absolutely. Therefore `float:left;` is redundant here.

Comment: I've added the 'px' at the end of the 600 however it's still not forcing the box to scroll. It's just adds a scroll bar down the side which doesn't do anything @HashemQolami

Comment: It ***is*** working [here](http://jsbin.com/gusizu/1/edit?html,css,output).

Comment: Jesus, could I be more stupid. Of course the Float is redundant here, without that it now works! Thank you so much for your help! @HashemQolami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be height:600px;

please add the px

Answer (score 0):

You must add max-height on div.

```
width: 200px;
max-height:50px;
left:20px;
top:10px;
padding:10px;
position: fixed;
float:left;
overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
height:600;
background-color:#ffffff;
border:solid 1px #e2e2e2;
```

Comment: No, the OP doesn't need to add `max-height`. The unit of value of `height` is missing.